# Databases and Qt

Tags: database, qt, qml

I am building an application in Qt/QML.
I have a table view of the database (PostgreSQL).
Is there a way to dynamically refresh my table if there is any change in the database.

One no-so-efficient way to do it is to keep sending periodic SQL queries.

Is there any automatic way to keep my view refreshed?
I am open to use any other Database also if required.

Comment: Are you using QSqlTableModel ?

Comment: Are you speaking of out of application modification to the database? Or is your application the only client?

Comment: Basically, the databases can be updated from other modules. But I want to reflect any modifications on my view of the database.

Answer (score 1):

Qt seems to support the NOTIFY mechanism of PostgreSQL databases. Googling for it it found some bug reports, so not sure of well implemented that is. Since I've never used it, I'll have to refer you to google.

Comment: This is what I am looking for, pls share any more details if you have.

Answer (score 1):

If you use QSqlTableModel (or an editable subclass of QSqlQueryModel) with QTableView, any edits made will immediately be visible.

Comment: Have you tried the [Qt SQL Examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/examples-sql.html), especially the Table Model example and the Cached Table example?